# Passive socket of IOLib throws out EADDRINUSE

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime

IOLib allows to create a passive socket to listen the clients' connection, before listen is called, we need to call (bind-address) to bind the socket to an specified address/port.

Well, the problem is that the first time I bind the socket to a port, it runs well, then I use C-c C-c in slime to terminate the thread, and run the program again, this time it throws out exception of EADDRINUSE:

```
 <SOCKET-ADDRESS-IN-USE-ERROR 98 :EADDRINUSE "address already in use", FD: 10>
```

I already set the reuse_addr option to bind-address like that:

```
   (bind-address socket
                 +ipv4-unspecified+
                 :port 1080
                 :reuse-addr t)
```

But I don't think this is the problem, because when I did the same thing in C, I use Ctrl+C to terminate the process, I can rebind the port, but in slime, the only solution is to restart emacs, it's really not conveninent, so How can I solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: I suspect that `C-c C-c` does not do what you think it does.  Have you looked at the list of threads after you thought you had terminated your thread?

Comment: How to show the list of threads, and how to select one to terminate?

Comment: I use the slime selector `t` for showing the threads.  You can kill a thread with `k` in that window.  Slime comes with a manual.

Comment: But in fact I only have one user thread running, what C-c C-c does is to kill this thread, along with killing the listening socket.

Answer (score 1):

When you exit a process, any open file descriptors (including network sockets) are closed, which is why it seems to work in C but not in CL. When a thread terminates, however, this doesn't happen.  You'll find that you'll get the desired behavior by using the restart-inferior-lisp command in SLIME.

Not all is lost, however.  If you wrap the function in the thread in an UNWIND-PROTECT form, you can arrange for the socket to be closed when the function is exited.